# How to sum a row in Excel with lookup values from a column based lookup?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have rows of values in columns AC to AU (but also some blanks)

I want to convert these values in a formula via a lookup and sum all the lookup values in a row.

For 1 cell I can use VLOOKUP(AC2,'Lookup_Table'!A2:B41,2) successfully

How do I sum the whole row of AC2 to AU2 with this kind of lookup?

Note the lookup is column oriented in a vertical lookup, the 'Lookup Table' is actually a worksheet.

This has stumped me for hours now!

```
         | AC | AD | AE ..Ax... AU
   Row 1 | 12 | 23 | 43 ..00... 67

    'Lookup table' worksheet
        A  |  B
        12 |  4
        23 |  2
        43 |  3
        67 |  5
```

The result should be 14 for the sample Row 1 data above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to use an array formula (`ctrl+shift+enter` instead of just `enter`). Generally I don't like array formulas (because they are easy for the uneducated to break), but I think it will work the best in your situation apart from reformatting your sheet or using helper columns.

```
{=SUM(IF(AC2:AU2=Lookup_Table!A2:A41,Lookup_Table!B2:B41))}
```

which should have {} around the whole thing if you entered it correctly.

Comment: THis makes sense to me. but getting #N/A as a result.  I have been able to use helper columns but interested in getting this solved

Comment: Do you have an #N/A error somewhere else in another one of your formulas? Pretty sure it can't return an #N/A otherwise.

Comment: Oh, actually, the arrays are different sizes, I wonder if that is the issue. I have to run to work though so I can check later.

Comment: @AndrewPym, updated my formula. I think you pretty much have to do this as an array formula. If you click through the formula using the `evaluate formula` button, it should be clear. Essentially outputting a true/false for each cell, and that determines which value to spit out (one from the table, or 0). This array is then run through `sum()` for the result.

Comment: Like magic. It is quote simple and elegant in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of `SUM` and `INDEX` functions, where AB in Lookup_Table is your index column for the table, and A! is the value you wish to lookup:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Lookup_Table!$AC$1,MATCH(A1,Lookup_Table!$AB:$AB,0)):INDEX(Lookup_Table!$AU$1,MATCH(A1,Lookup_Table!$AB:$AB,0)))
```

Comment: Struggling with your answer. there is a reference to K1 which throws me a bit.  In the lookup table Column A is the index, Column B is the value I wish to lookup / pull back

Comment: Sorry, `K1` should have been `Lookup_Table!$AU$1` - got my code a bit mixed up after testing.

Comment: Still struggling. I have provided an example now

Comment: Misunderstood your question, answer from Jacob Bolda is the one you want.